# Random football matches in php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I don't know how it happens in international football but in my country (Portugal) we have football matches divided by journeys. What I want to do is to make random football macthes between all the teams in a championship.

Example: (4 teams)

TeamA,TeamB,TeamC,TeamD

***1st journey***

- TeamA vs TeamB
- TeamC vs TeamD

***2nd journey***

- TeamB vs TeamC
- TeamD vs TeamA

***3rd journey***

- TeamD vs TeamB
- TeamC vs TeamA

//below games are easy, we just need to swap teams.

***4th journey***

- TeamB vs TeamA
- TeamD vs TeamC

***5th journey***

- TeamC vs TeamB
- TeamA vs TeamD

***6th journey***

- TeamB vs TeamD
- TeamA vs TeamC

***Rules***

- In each championship, each team can only play with another once
- After playing at home, the team becomes the visiting team in the next journey (with some exceptions because this isn't always possible)

I tried doing this with javascript and php but the result was not as expected. I search the web for a problem similar to this one, but no luck.

Can someone help me? At least with a theory?

Comment: Good football there... Just do it once and then reverse the team order for the second match. There are many many ways of doing this. Do you want to save your results to a database or you just want different results each time you load your site?.

Comment: I want to save them into a database ;) This will create the macthes for a football championship

Comment: Let's think about it this way: I assume Portugal's league works as the spanish one, ok?. Two matches for every pair of teams... So, let's eliminate the second round of matches, as it's the same as the first but in reverse, right?. Then, the first round just faces each team with every other team, right?. You can start assigning them in order (say TeamA vs B, A vs C, A vs D) and then just shuffle the results. Check if the match already exists for each iteration and you'll have a lot of work done. And please, take Cristiano Ronaldo back :P.

Comment: Lol I don't care about CR, I'm sick of him already xD Yes, I think it works like spanish league. The problem is, on verification process, in order to see if teamA has already played with another team, when we have lots of teams, the script will blow up with so many verifications.

Comment: Plus, how do you recommend to save data? Do I save the team's ids? I think it is the better aproach. Do I save them in an array?

Comment: Take it one step at a time: first, a table with your teams - say, id and name - then a matchs table - say, number, team_id_local, team_id_visitor. Take one team and match it up with all the others. Then, for the rest, do the same operation but check first that they haven't been matched yet. You should be doing less and less inserts until the last of them. When every team is matched with every other team, select all matches and insert them again in reverse order - visitor and local - for the second row of matches. Don't worry about blowing up php: it is sturdier than it seems.